# Applied force vs restoring force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, spring

Let us take a horizontal spring block system where the block is initially at the mean position. If we pull the block applying a force $F$,then by Newton's $3rd$ law,the block will pull us by the exact same force. This force is the restoring force in the spring. Is this concept correct? *I am saying it from the fact that when we pull a string by a force $F$,the string also applies a force on us which is the tension force,and they are equal in magnitude.*

If my above statement is correct, then we can say applied force $F=$ restoring force $f_s=kx$. Now if we make that horizontal spring vertical,the applied force now is $mg$ which is a constant force. But we deduced $F=kx$,so that will imply $mg=kx$. But $kx$ is a variable and $mg$ is a constant. So,how is it possible? Please kindly clear my misconception.

Comment: the x here refers to the displacement of the spring at the maximum extension, so it isn't a variable but a fixed maximum length value that depends on m, g and k

Comment: Sorry if i am being dumb but don't we use the equation $W=\int kx dx$ in calculating the work done by restoring force in compressing a string? Here $x$ is not a variable,which is why restoring force keeps changing and we needed to use integration.

Answer (score 1):

> Now if we make that horizontal spring vertical,the applied force now
> is $mg$ which is a constant force. But we deduced $F=kx$,so that will
> imply $mg=kx$. But $kx$ is a variable and $mg$ is a constant. So,how
> is it possible?

The restoring force $kx$ is equal and opposite to the applied force $mg$ per Newton's 3rd law *at each value of the displacement $x$*. What changes (varies) is the net force acting on the mass as the spring stretches.

If the mass $m$ is initially hung from the spring in its relaxed position (before it begins to stretch or, $x=0$), the restoring force the spring exerts on the mass is zero and the force the mass exerts on the spring is zero per Newton's 3rd law. But there will then be a net downward force acting on the mass of $mg$ giving it an initial acceleration of $g$ per Newton's second law.

As the spring stretches, the restoring force the spring exerts on the mass increases as does the force the mass exerts on the spring by an equal amount per Newton's 3rd law.  But now the increase in the restoring force on $m$ results in a decrease in the net force acting on $m$ causing it to decelerate. When the spring reaches its maximum displacement of $x=mg/k$, the net force on the mass is zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So basically,in a nutshell,the mg force of the block and the spring restoring force are NOT the action reaction pair? Well obviously as spring force is electromagnetic and gravity is gravitational, but I'm just confirming

Comment: The restoring force of the spring acting up on the block and the force of gravity acting down on the block are not the action-reaction pair. They are the external forces acting on  the block that determine the net force on the block per N2L. It is the restoring force acting up on the block by the spring and the force the block exerts down on the spring at the location where the spring and block are connected that comprise the action reaction pair per N3L.

Comment: Thank you so much,you explained in very precise and simple language,but i have a conceptual doubt,you said the force exerted by the block on spring and spring restoring force are action reaction pair,but assume,that at some extension x,the block is suddenly removed,therefore the force by block on spring becomes 0,but,still the spring restoring force exists,that is -kx,which would make the string oscillate,but,since action force(force by block on spring) was removed,the reaction force(spring restoring force) should also have been vanished/removed,but it is still there,how r dey action reaction?

Answer (score 1):

If we compare both situations, in the first one a person is applying a force ($F$), and get a reaction from the spring ($kx$). For each value of $F$ there is a given $x$ of equilibrium. If it is not the equilibrium situation, (general case) the equation of movement is: $F - kx = ma$

In the second case, the Earth (gravity) applies a force on the spring ($mg$). Again there is a given $x$ of equilibrium for that force. Out of equilibrium: $mg - kx = ma$

Maybe what leads to confusion is that we don't realize that when we pull a spring, we apply normally a variable force to stretch it, increasing our force as necessary until the desired displacement. The earth applies really a constant force.